# Azure AppService: how can I make a request to an API on a private network from a docker container?

Tags: docker, azure-web-app-service

> Preamble: my understanding of networking is close to zero, apologies if my terminology is unclear.

I wrote a simple dotnet web API, which I published as a docker container on Azure AppService / Web app, hosted on a Linux App Service plan.

I can access my API just fine, but I am running into a problem. I need to make requests from within my API, to another API which is not publicly accessible.

On my local machine, once connected to that VPN, I can run the container locally and make these requests by using `docker run --network=host`, and everything works as expected.

Where I am running into a wall is, how can I achieve the same result when deploying that container into Azure AppService?
The resource group my AppService is on is the same as the API I am trying to call, and I believe they are on the same network.
I presume I cannot do the equivalent of `--network=host` there (as far as I can tell, when the image is pulled from ACR, AppService decides how it is launched), so how can I call non public resources from within my container on AppService?

Comment: you can use the vnet integration with custom DNS server to point to the API's private IP.